# Select from joined table only if record exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
Customers.CustomerName AS FullName,
Customers.Id AS CustomerId,
Customers.UserRoleId AS UserRoleId,
Customers.Email AS Email,
IFNULL(Customers.StudentId, '') AS CustomersStudentId,
IFNULL(Customers.MagentoId, '') AS MagentoId,

Sections.Id AS SectionId,
Sections.SectionNumber AS SectionNumber,
Sections.SectionName AS SectionName,

Courses.Id AS CourseId,
IFNULL(Courses.CourseName, '') AS CourseName,
IFNULL(Courses.CourseNumber,'') AS CourseNumber,
IFNULL(Courses.CourseDepartment, '') AS CourseDepartment,
IFNULL(Courses.Notes, '') AS CourseNotes,
IFNULL(Courses.Year, '') AS CourseYear,
IFNULL(Courses.CourseType, '') AS CourseType,

StudentsCourses.Id AS StudentsCoursesId,
IFNULL(StudentsCourses.StudentId, '') AS StudentsCoursesStudentId,

IFNULL(SiteProfile.StudentIdField, '') AS StudentIdField,
IFNULL(SiteProfile.SchoolEmailDomain, '') AS SchoolEmailDomain,

IFNULL(Orders.Id, '') AS OrderId

FROM Customers
    LEFT JOIN StudentsCourses ON Customers.Id = StudentsCourses.CustomerId
    LEFT JOIN Sections ON StudentsCourses.SectionId = Sections.Id
    LEFT JOIN Courses ON StudentsCourses.CourseId = Courses.Id
    LEFT JOIN BooksCourses ON Courses.Id = BooksCourses.CourseId
    LEFT JOIN Products ON BooksCourses.ISBN = Products.ISBN
    LEFT JOIN EbookVendors ON Products.EbookVendorId = EbookVendors.Id
    LEFT JOIN Orders ON Customers.Id = Orders.CustomerId
    LEFT JOIN SiteProfile ON Courses.SchoolCode = SiteProfile.SchoolCode

WHERE Customers.Id <> 10
    AND StudentsCourses.SectionId IS NOT NULL
    AND StudentsCourses.Delete <> 2
    AND Courses.SchoolCode = '{$criteria["school_code"]}'
    AND Courses.Year = {$criteria["year"]}
    AND Courses.CourseType LIKE '{$criteria["term"]}'
```

Records will always exist in the `Customers` table. But sometimes there will be no associated records in any of the other joined tables.

How do I modify the query so that the additional `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses don't break the results when there are only records in the `Customers` table?

EDIT:

When the record only exists in `Customers`, I want that record and I want the `WHERE` clauses that don't pertain to the `Customers` table to be ignored.

If the record exists in a joined table, I want the `WHERE` clause that pertains to that joined table to work.

Comment: explain better ... please ....  you  want only the result that match between  customers and others table  or you want both .... alias the result for match and for  not match  between customers and others tables ?

Comment: Edited with more clarity

Comment: Move the join limiting critiera on records not in the customer table to the joins.  Example: `LEFT JOIN StudentsCourses ON Customers.Id = StudentsCourses.CustomerId AND   StudentsCourses.SectionId IS NOT NULL
    AND StudentsCourses.Delete <> 2`  The limit is applied before the join thus keeping the customer records when the join to studentsCourses would be null.  MOST of the time when using outer joins the join limiting criteria needs to be executed before the join. OR you have to account for nulls like others have done in answers below.

Comment: In short, change 'WHERE' to 'AND'

Comment: @Strawberry - that is not in short, it just does not make sense.  Changing where to and would cause this query to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the where statement to deal with nulls.  Like this

```
WHERE Customers.Id <> 10
  --  AND StudentsCourses.SectionId IS NOT NULL
    AND COALESCE(StudentsCourses.Delete,0) <> 2
    AND COALESCE(Courses.SchoolCode,'{$criteria["school_code"]}') = '{$criteria["school_code"]}'
    AND COALESCE(Courses.Year,{$criteria["year"]}) = {$criteria["year"]}
    AND (Courses.CourseType is null or Courses.CourseType LIKE '{$criteria["term"]}')
```

When you left join and the value does not exist you will have null for those items -- to still see the row you need to not have your where statement filter out those items.

There is another way to do it which is to put the criteria in the joins.  So for example course type would look like this:

```
  LEFT JOIN Courses ON StudentsCourses.CourseId = Courses.Id and Courses.CourseType LIKE '{$criteria["term"]}'
```

If you do this then you don't need to add the filter to the where -- it will only be applied to the join and will return null for the table columns if the join does not exist.

Comment: Awesome. Both answers have shown me new things that are possible with SQL. I will try them and get back!

Comment: @LXXIII - nice!  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

When you left join, you're going to get NULLs in the fields for which there is no corresponding "right" record, so you have to account for that:

```
WHERE Customers.Id <> 10
    -- AND StudentsCourses.SectionId IS NOT NULL 
    AND (StudentsCourses.Delete <> 2 OR StudentsCourses.Delete IS NULL)
    AND (Courses.SchoolCode = '{$criteria["school_code"]}' OR Courses.SchoolCode IS NULL)
    AND ( Courses.Year = {$criteria["year"]} OR Courses.Year IS NULL)
    AND (Courses.CourseType LIKE '{$criteria["term"]}' OR Courses.CourseType IS NULL)
```

Comment: If `StudentsCourses.Delete` is `null`, it's possible the record exists, but the Delete flag as not been set. I would want that record to show in that scenario.

Comment: @LXXII - just like in my example this will show that record.

Answer (score 1):

Both wrong.  You can't have a query that returns two different shapes of tuples: these columns from here if this exists, but those columns from both here and there if hat exists.  One query, one shape.

That having been sternly said, let's relax a little bit.

Just do an outer join, and if the data to be joined doesn't exist (= can't be found), NULL values will be silently, painlessly filled into the indicated columns.  "Populated" is a fancier word for that.

Comment: I think you're right, because when I did successfully get the query to work as intended, I ended up getting double entries. A student would show up with each of their courses, but then an extra entry would be returned with `NULL` as the Course. I ended up separating it into two queries...